# Importing globally and locally

Tags: python, import, module

I created a module which is going to be used in several python scripts. The structure is as follows:

Main file:

```
import numpy as np
from mymodule import newfunction
f = np.arange(100,200,1)
a = np.zeros(np.shape(f))
c = newfunction(f)
```

mymodule.py:

```
def newfunction(f):
    import numpy as np
    b = np.zeros(np.shape(f))
    return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np
```

Don't mind the functionality of this program, but the problem is that when I run it, I get "NameError: global name 'zeros' is not defined".

What am I missing out on here?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but... why not stick the import at the top of mymodule.py?

Comment: Your error can't come from your code: there is no global "zeros" used in it anywhere.  There's a global "arange" though, so that should be the error :-)

Comment: I have also tried that... Same error :/ I have tried to insert "import numpy as np" both at the top of the module (outside the function) and locally within the function.

Comment: @williamx: you need to use `np.arange`, not `arange`.

Comment: That was just a typo... The problem is that the np-methods don't get recognized within the function, even though I import the numpy module outside and inside the module.

Comment: After your recent edit, it works for me.  PLEASE post the code you're running, i.e., copy-paste it.

Comment: @williamx: You don't want to do the import inside newfunction, as this creates a local variable (np) each time you run newfunction.  You want to put the import at the top of your program.

Comment: Hmm, was `import numpy as np` inside `def newfunction(f):` when I answered this question?

Comment: @Tomasz: nope.  He added it later in the post.  We don't know what's in his real code though :-)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... I just tried to write a simplified version of my code, which confusingly enough just worked :) It seems to be solved now. Probably some caching in ipython or something which confused me. Anyway, the solution was to import numpy as np in the module outside the function definition. Thanks!

Comment: @williamx, that's why it's important to copy-paste code.  I am voting to close since it wasn't a real question to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

mymodule.py doesn't see:

```
  import numpy as np
```

statement(s). "import" statement in Python doesn't work like #include in C++, it merely creates new dictionary of objects contained in imported module. If you want to use 'np' identifier within that dictionary, you have to explicitly import it there.

Regarding

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import numpy as np
```

-- this is only called when you execute mymodule.py as standalone script, which probably is not the case in this question.

EDIT:

OP changed sample code, by adding `import numpy as np` inside his function, and my answer is for the original question.

Comment: mymodule.py works perfect as a standalone script, but when I call it from the main .py-file I get the "global name .. not defined" error.

Comment: @williamx - if you ran it as standalone script, then numpy is imported as np, so everything works like a charm. But when you import mymoduly.py to main .py file, numpy is not imported!